# getting html table data via bs4 into python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from a twitch sub count site to see various twitch channel data. I want to be able to type in a username and get the rank of the channel and current sub count.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 

url = "https://twitchanalysis.top/topsubs"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 
Safari/537.3"}

client = Request(url=url, headers=headers)
page_html = urlopen(client).read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
db = {}
table = page_soup.find("table", id="topsubs_table")

for cell in page_soup.find_all('td')[3]:
    cell = page_soup.find_all('td')
    db[cell[2].text] = [cell[0].text, cell[3].text]
print(db)
```

However, this code only returns the no.1 channel when run. It should return all the channels on the first page. I'm not sure what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all records you have to traverse through rows.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = "https://twitchanalysis.top/topsubs"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
client = Request(url=url, headers=headers)
page_html = urlopen(client).read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
db = {}
table = page_soup.find("table", id="topsubs_table")
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    cell = row.find_all('td')
    if 'This is a spot for an advertisement' in cell[0].text:
         continue
    else:
        db[cell[2].text] = [cell[0].text, cell[3].text]
print(db)
```

**Output**:

```
{'montanablack88': ['9', '23192'], 'nickmercs': ['4', '25314'], 'pokimane': ['36', '11173'], 'gladd': ['6', '24422'], 'criticalrole': ['16', '17529'], 'maximilian_dood': ['31', '12111'], 'ratirl': ['20', '15106'], 'cohhcarnage': ['12', '20752'], 'jasonr': ['40', '10313'], 'forsen': ['43', '9890'], 'teepee': ['23', '14090'], 'jerma985': ['41', '10180'], 'BobbyPoffGaming': ['19', '16281'], 'castro_1021': ['5', '24670'], 'drlupo': ['7', '23886'], 'alanzoka': ['30', '12521'], 'trainwreckstv': ['29', '13087'], 'noway4u_sir': ['21', '14611'], 'dakotaz': ['39', '10551'], 'ludwig': ['38', '10805'], 'rallied': ['42', '9893'], 'cdnthe3rd': ['48', '9103'], 'therealknossi': ['13', '20563'], 'lord_kebun': ['33', '11311'], 'xqcow': ['2', '32624'], 'littlesiha': ['44', '9693'], 'zerator': ['25', '13498'], 'chocotaco': ['27', '13373'], 'paymoneywubby': ['32', '11972'], 'timthetatman': ['14', '19526'], 'tfue': ['18', '16604'], 'auronplay': ['47', '9590'], 'sacriel': ['28', '13123'], 'lirik': ['17', '17497'], 'pestily': ['15', '18013'], 'rubius': ['35', '11223'], 'FORMAL': ['22', '14200'], 'drdisrespect': ['3', '29027'], 'admiralbahroo': ['10', '22752'], 'papaplatte': ['24', '13519'], 'nick28t': ['49', '9101'], 'joshog': ['34', '11284'], 'shlorox': ['37', '10980'], 'loltyler1': ['45', '9680'], 'gronkh': ['26', '13391'], 'gamesdonequick': ['1', '35885'], 'summit1g': ['8', '23787'], 'MOONMOON': ['11', '22220'], 'zanoxvii': ['46', '9677']}
```